# RNAseq: Convert RNA identifiers to Genes

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am using DEseq2 for DE analysis and want to analyze a publshed data set.
However, the count matrix provided does not show ENSEMBL gene IDs but mRNA transcript ids instead, i.e. the first column looks like that: XM_0176201594.2

Could somebody tell me how to convert, or fetch from GTF to get the usual count matrix that serves as input for DESeq2? Basically, we are looking at a matrix, where several lines correspond to the same gene, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not very sure what id you have try (can't google?)... if it is refseq you can try something like http://crazyhottommy.blogspot.com/2014/09/converting-gene-ids-using-bioconductor.html

Comment: and you do this after the analysis, otherwise you end up with duplicate row names

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand your second comment. Shouldn't I first do this and merge the duplicates summing up their count values and then perform the DE analysis? Otherwise DESeq2 is gonna treat splice variants as independent genes. Let me know if I am wrong!

Comment: what I meant is, you cannot change the row names of the matrix before doing DESeq2, as you will end up with duplicated rownames. You either just run it on this transcript matrix and have a table with geneIDs

Comment: or like you said, you can take the mean of all transcripts and use that as genes, then run it.. if you are still having problems doing it, can you state what is the organism you have?